# save is not a function when updating data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongoose to update some data on my mongoDB database. I use the `.find` method then assign a new value to my existing object key but when I save it I get error `result.save()` is not a function. Where did I go wrong and how can I fix it. Thanks in advance.

```js
const mySchema = require('../models/schemaPath')

mySchema.find()
  .then(async(result) => {
    Object.assign(result, {
      "myData": 'someData',
    })
    result.save()
      .then(async(result) => {
        console.log('Done')
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Comment: find returns array, if you want to find by id and update, you can use findByIdAndUpdate method.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to change here:

1. Find function callbacks with an array and you're trying to deal JSON actions on it.
2. save is not a function to update.

If you're trying to update a record of MongoDB,
use something like this :

```
mySchema.findOneAndUpdate({}, { "myData": 'someData' }).then((data) => {...}).catch((e) =>{...})
```

use filter parameters if you want to update the record having particular data.

Hope this answer helps you!!
Feel free to comment if you get any errors or doubts and don't miss to look at
[mongoose document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html)